# Need to find Fourier series of the following graph

Tags: fourier-analysis

[image][image]

Need to find Fourier series of the following graph.....question is also written in figure.

Comment: ...and you want to do this in *Mathematica*? Do you already have an expression for the function represented by the red graph?

Comment: 1) Yes...i want to find Find Fourier Series/Coefficients with Mathematica.

Comment: 2) I dont have the expression for the function represented in red graph....want mathematica to find it

Comment: i can provide the piece-wise data ...and get the FS ...maybe??

Comment: That would help.

Comment: Now i have added another picture with the generic piece-wise data..thanks

Comment: I am positive that you can build up the expression for the general Fourier coefficient from this simple integral: `Integrate[Sin[\[Omega] t] Exp[I n t], {t, a, b}]`. Pleas note that copyable code in Mathematica syntax is usually preferred over images.